# Retrieving binary image data from the database resulting none

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, winforms

I have saved the screenshot image to the database and convert it into binary code. But, once I want to retrieve it, only the file name appear, but the image did not.

How can I solve this?

Here is the code that I am using to save the image to the database (When user click on the picture box, it will capture the image (screenshot)):

```
public string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Example/Database/db1.accdb;";

public static void AddScreenshot()
    {
        _workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

        string _dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd - MM - yyyy - hh - mm - ss tt");

        string _path = "D:/Example/Screenshots/Screenshot " + _dateTime + ".jpg";

        string _fileName = "Screenshot " + _dateTime + ".jpg";

        try
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(_workingRectangle.Width, _workingRectangle.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(_workingRectangle.Left, _workingRectangle.Top), Point.Empty, _workingRectangle.Size);
                }

                bitmap.Save(_path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [Capture] ([Path], [FileName], [Data]) VALUES (@Path, @FileName, @Data)";

                conn.Open();

                FileStream fsBLOBFile = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                Byte[] bytBLOBData = new Byte[fsBLOBFile.Length];

                fsBLOBFile.Read(bytBLOBData, 0, bytBLOBData.Length);

                fsBLOBFile.Close();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Path", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Path"].Value = _path;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@FileName", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = _fileName;

                    OleDbParameter prm = new OleDbParameter("@Data", OleDbType.VarBinary, bytBLOBData.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, bytBLOBData);

                    command.Parameters.Add(prm);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

and this is how I retrieve it:

```
private void RetrieveScreenshot()
    {
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Path], [FileName], [Data] FROM [Capture]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(_dt);

                    GridView1.DataSource = _dt;

                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    adapter.Dispose();
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

And here is the image, stored in the folder:

[image]

Your answer much appreciated to me!

Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to convert your binary data to the image before binding to the grid or `OnBind` event you can change the data to image.And why you are tagged it as `Winforms `

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the `BLOB` to the byte array and then convert that byte array to image.

This is the way to convert the `BLOB` to the byte array,

```
 byte[] byteArrayIn = (byte[])_dt.row[0]["data"];
```

This is the method which you can use to convert the byte array to the image

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
 {
   return Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn));
 }
```

And all this has to done either before setting the datasource to the gridview  first convert and then set. Or you can use the [OnRowDataBound event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert each byte array to image and then setting to the grid row.

Comment: Where should I put the code into @Coder of Code? Thank you

Comment: You need to put this code on the `rowdatabound` event

Comment: Thank you @Coder of Code, will try first and then accept this as answer if it is working as expected